# Regular expression to remove Handlebars comment

Tags: javascript, regex, handlebars.js

I have a string with Handlebars template and would like to remove comments:

```
{{! .... }}
```

Could you help me suggest some regular expression. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex itself itsn't that hard, `/{{![\S\s]*?}}/g` seems to do it fine. The important part is the `[\S\s]*?` which says any character in the set [non-whitspace, whitespace], any amount of repetitions but as few as possible. Using both the whitespace and non-whitespace lets us match all characters including linebreaks. If we leave out the `?` (which is "as few as possible") it would keep looking from the first comment to the last `}}` in the string which obviously is bad.

```html
<script>
  var template = '{{#if true }}\n  {{! Nothing to see\nhere! }}\n{{/if}}'.replace(/{{![\S\s]*?}}/g, '');
  console.log(template)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx, it works fine for one line comment, but not for multiline.

Comment: For multiline comments `var pattern = /{{!.[^]*?}}/g;` works fine. `[^]` to allow matching newlines